# How do Personal Finance companies get access to their customers investment accounts?

Tags: programming, equities, interactive-brokers

I want to create an app that centralizes all the customer's investment accounts into one platform where they can view/monitor their trading positions across all brokerage accounts. How do apps like Mint, or Interactive Brokers do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more about software development than Quantitative Finance.

Answer (score 3):

I would reach out to [SnapTrade](https://snaptrade.com/). You would connect your platform to them, and in turn they allow your customers to connect numerous brokerage accounts to your platform.

Answer (score 0):

A common term for this function is *Account aggregation* "Account aggregation is a process in which data from many—or all—of an individual's or household's financial accounts are collected in one place. It is also referred to as financial data aggregation." One company that has built this kind of software layer is Yodlee, started 20 years ago and now owned by Envestnet.

There are various implementation techniques in use. In the first one the company automatically logs on to the customer's account at night, using ID and password which the customer has provided to them. The required data is captured using *screen-scraping* of the bank's regular user interface. This poses obvious security issues. More recently formal API's for data acquisition have been developped, for example by the company Plaid. It takes quite a bit of effort to develop interfaces to a large number of Finl Institutions, each of which may have some particularities. It is not something one would easily develop from scratch. Hence the existence of companies that specialize in this function.

The competitor SnapTrade has aready been mentioned. Another one is MX.